# javafx how do I add a list of available enums to ComboBoxTableCell?

Tags: javafx-8

Can't figure out how to add a list of enums to a table with ComboBox. For now the code doesn't compile, it fails in grade.toString() of the StringConverter.
Below is a basic sample of what I'm working with. Ultimately I'd love to be able to do three things:

1. Display a ComboBox with all available enums
2. Pre-populate it with current grade, if one exists.
3. Be able to change the selected and update the student's object with the new selection.

Can anyone please help?

```
public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    try {
      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      TableView<Student> tbl = new TableView<>();
      TableColumn<Student, Grade> col = new TableColumn<>("Grade");

      ObservableList<Grade> grades = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Grade.values());

      col.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Grade>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Grade grade) {
          return grade.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public Grade fromString(String s) {
          return Grade.valueOf(s);
        }
      }, grades));

      tbl.getColumns().add(col);

      Student a = new Student();
      a.grade = Grade.A;
      a.name = "Mark";
      tbl.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(a));

      root.getChildren().add(tbl);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Enum

```
public enum Grade {
  A (5),
  B (4),
  C (3),
  D (2),
  F (1);

  int gradePoints;

  Grade(int gradePoints) {
    this.gradePoints = gradePoints;
  }

  public int getGradePoints() {
    return gradePoints;
  }
}
```

and Student class:

```
public class Student {
    String name; // name has the default value null 
    int age; // age has the default value 0 
    boolean isScienceMajor; // isScienceMajor has default value false 
    char gender; // gender has default value '\u0000' 
    Grade grade;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. The code compiles just fine. If the code will work is another topic though (iirc a `StringConverter` needs to be able to deal with `null`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to define values for your table cells**

You are not telling the system how to find out what the value of a cell is.

You need to set a cell value factory on the column.  The easiest way to do that is to make your Student class use and expose JavaFX properties, then [set the cell value factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)) to a [propertyValueFactory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) naming the property which is associated with a given column.  For your example, this would be the `"grade"` property.

**How to make cells editable**

If you want a table or particular columns to be editable, you need to specify that [the table is editable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setEditable-boolean-), and the [columns are editable](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#setEditable(boolean)).  You also need to expose appropriate setters or property methods in the class which defines your item types.  For your example, this means defining appropriate properties and/or getter and setter functions in the `Student` class for each of the fields you want to be able to associate with the table.

As suggested by fabian in comments, for robustness, it is a good idea to have the `StringConverter` for the `ComboBoxTableCell` be able to deal with null values (as in the sample code provided below).

**How the user edits items**

To start editing a cell, the user needs to double click on the cell to convert it from a display mode to an edit mode (then the combobox will be displayed, but without the dropdown).  Then click on the combobox to drop it down, then choose the appropriate grade from the dropdown, after which the value will be saved and the cell switched back to read mode.  The system will know. from the property value definition, to call the appropriate setter to save the newly chosen grade back to the grade property of the underlying item.

**Example Application**

[image]

*App.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        TableView<Student> tbl = new TableView<>();
        tbl.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Student, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setEditable(false);
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        TableColumn<Student, Grade> gradeCol = new TableColumn<>("Grade");
        gradeCol.setEditable(true);

        ObservableList<Grade> grades = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Grade.values());
        gradeCol.setCellFactory(
                ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(
                        new StringConverter<>() {
                            @Override
                            public String toString(Grade grade) {
                                return grade != null ? grade.toString() : null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public Grade fromString(String s) {
                                return s != null ? Grade.valueOf(s) : null;
                            }
                        },
                        grades
                )
        );

        gradeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("grade"));

        tbl.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, gradeCol);

        Student aStudent = new Student(
                "Mark", Grade.A
        );
        tbl.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(aStudent));

        root.getChildren().add(tbl);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

*Student.java*

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class Student {
    private ReadOnlyStringWrapper name;
    private ObjectProperty<Grade> grade;

    public Student(String name, Grade grade) {
        this.name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(name);
        this.grade = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(grade);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public Grade getGrade() {
        return grade.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Grade> gradeProperty() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(Grade grade) {
        this.grade.set(grade);
    }
}
```

The Grade class is unchanged from the definition in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm. Even ignoring the properties, I would have never figured out that I needed to explicitly set the table to be editable.